# Retrieve key in dictionnary AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to find the root key of my dictionary in AngularJS.
Here is my code : http://jsbin.com/vidihucihexo/1/edit

I want to display "`aUniqueID1`" if I do "`{{match.matchs}}`" it's showing :

```
{
    "aUniqueID1":{
        "date":"2014-09-07 13:00:00",
        "guest_player":"Me",
        "host_player":"Tom",
        "odds":{
            "guest":"2.80",
            "host":"2.25",
            "null":"2.85"
        },
        "score":"0 - 0"
    },
    "aUniqueID2":{
        "date":"2014-09-07 18:30:00",
        "guest_player":"Bryan",
        "host_player":"Me",
        "odds":{
            "guest":"3.25",
            "host":"1.98",
            "null":"2.95"
        },
        "score":"0 - 0"
    }
}
```

I just want to show the value key `aUniqueID1` (this text, not the dictionary).

Ideas?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <li class="item" ng-repeat="(key, item) in match.matchs">
    {{key}} 
    {{item.host_player}} vs {{item.guest_player}}
  </li>
```

[Here is](http://jsbin.com/didofevaneca/1/edit) your modified code

Comment: Yes, this seems like undocumented feature but it works with Angular 1.3.0-rc as well

Comment: undocumented? I just posted the link to the documentation documenting this feature..

Comment: From documentation (and example) it looks like you have to give property names for `key` and `item` (which would be impossible since the property names are 'aUniqueID1', 'aUniqueID2' in this scenario). So I would say that fact that angular binds object's property name to `key` and it's value to `value` is undocumented feature. I fact you can use any literals like `id` or `match` and it will still work.

Comment: "(key, value) in expression – where key and value can be any user defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the collection to enumerate. For example: (name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}." I find that hard to missunderstand. Anyway; he got his problem solved.